# How to address CWE-502 for Swift's Codable

Tags: swift, secure-coding, snyk

Snyk.io has alerted me to a CWE-502 issue with a Swift class that implements `Codable`.

> Deserialization of untrusted data (CWE-502), is when the application
> deserializes untrusted data without sufficiently verifying that the
> resulting data will be valid, letting the attacker to control the
> state or the flow of the execution.

The class is defined as `class Foo: Codable { ...`.

The report goes onto suggest a NSSecureCopying fix which I don't think is relevant.

> In Swift, the NSSecureCoding protocol
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssecurecoding)
> was added to mitigate object-injection or deserialization attacks. The
> analysis found serializable classes that do not fully conform to the
> NSSecureCoding protocol. To prevent this issue from being detected,
> all serializable must conform to the NSSecureCoding protocol by:
>
> Extend the NSSecureCoding class Adding a boolean variable to the class
> (supportsSecureCoding) and setting the value to true Ensuring that
> only safe decoding methods are used in the class init?(coder:
> NSCoding) constructor, such as decodeObjectOfClass()

- Can this be address with a code change?
- Is this a valid issue? Perhaps it's a false positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Snyk. :)

This finding does not appear anymore. It was removed from the Snyk ruleset and Codable is not flagged anymore.

Traditional cases using `NSCoding` will still be flagged though:

```
class Vehicle: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var make: String

    open func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(make, forKey: "make")
    }
    
    public init(make aMake) {
        self.make = aMake
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let aMake = coder.decodeObject(of:NSString.self, forKey: "make") as? String
        else { return nil }
        
        self.init(make: aMake)
    }

}
```